# How to update sitemap automatically in React js

Tags: reactjs, sitemap

I am using react-router-sitemap to generate sitemap.xml and successfully generated file in public folder after running **npm run sitemap**. But I need to update this file whenever I add new URL's to the site without creating build.
I am using python/Django for backend

I followed this blog [how to generate sitemap for react website](https://www.amitsn.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-sitemap-for-your-react-website-with-dynamic-content)

Is there any way by which I can run **npm run sitemap** after some conditions

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what the conditions are that you're looking to trigger the command, the blog post you linked actually gives a good way to do this, if you scroll down to the end of the blog post it mentions using a predeploy hook;

```
"scripts": {
  "predeploy": "npm run sitemap"
}
```

using this predeploy hook will run `npm run sitemap` before it runs `npm run deploy` whenever you deploy your application, assuming you deploy your application by running `npm run deploy` and assuming there's also a deploy script in your `package.json`

Comment: But for this we need to deploy the project everytime a new URL adds in site. I want to run sitemap-generator every time a new URL  add to the site.